# Getting slug from url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, posts

How can i get slug from url in wordpress. For example my url is `https://ww.test.com/test-page/test-post/data-to-get` how can i get `data-to-get` from url in wordpress. I tried following code

```
global $wp;
$current_url = home_url( add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request ) );
```

what is wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built-in function for that in wordpress: `url_to_postid`.

```
<?php
global $wp;
$current_url = $wp->request;
$post_id = url_to_postid($current_url);
$slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', $post_id );
echo $slug;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your output using below methods.

1. by using Global post variable.

   ```
    <?php 
      global $post; 
      $post_slug = $post->post_name; 
     ?>
   ```
2. using PHP

   ```
    <?php
      global $wp;
      $current_url = $wp->request;
      echo substr($current_url , strrpos($current_url , '/') + 1);
     ?>
   ```

Suppose URL: https://ww.test.com/test-page/test-post/data-to-get

OUTPUT: data-to-get

I have checked and it's work for me.
Let me know if this works for you.